# Why is this regex being greedy?

Tags: c#, regex, non-greedy

I am trying to extract all links that have /thumb/ in it within ""'s. Actually i only need to use the images src. I dont know if images will end with jpg or if there will be case sensitivity problems, etc. I really only care about the full link.

```
m = Regex.Match(page, @"""(.+?/thumbs/.+?)""");
//...
var thumbUrl = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

My full code

```
    var page = DownloadWebPage(url);
    var reg = new Regex(@"Elements\s+\((.*)\)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    var m = reg.Match(page);
    var szEleCount= m.Groups[1].Value;
    int eleCount = int.Parse(szEleCount);

    m = Regex.Match(page, @"""(.+?/thumbs/.+?)""");
    while (m.Success)
    {
        var thumbUrl = m.Groups[1].Value;
        //i break here to see a problem
        m = m.NextMatch();
    }
```

thumbUrl looks like

center\"> ... lot of text, no /thumbs/ ...  src=\"http://images.fdhkdhfkd.com/thumbs/dfljdkl/22350.jpg

Comment: FYI, the `Multiline` option isn't doing anything for you.  If you want the dot to match line separators you should use `Singleline` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way a reluctant (non-greedy) quantifier works is, once it starts to match, it stops at the first opportunity.  What you're trying to do is match the minimum amount of text that meets your criteria, which isn't the same thing; you still have to make sure it doesn't *start* matching before you want it to.  As others have suggested, you can do that by replacing the `.+?` in your regex with something that doesn't match quotes, like `[^""]+`.

But that still leaves you with a performance problem.  In your example, the regex starts matching when it sees the quote in `center">`; when it reaches the quote at `src="` (assuming you've changed the `.+?` to `[^""]+`) it will abort that match attempt an move on.  The next attempt, starting at the quote in `src="` will succeed.  So you're getting the right result now, but you're still wasting a lot of time on that first, failed match attempt.

The key to writing fast regexes is to make sure that, if a match attempt is going to fail, it fails as quickly as possible.  For example, I think it's safe to assume you don't want any angle brackets between the `"` and `/thumbs/`, so add them to the set of characters you don't want to match: `[^""<>]+`.  Now, any match attempt starting at the quote in `center">` it will be aborted at the very next position.

There are other things you can do to further optimize the regex, involving atomic groups and negative lookaheads, but this will probably be as fast as you need:

```
@"""([^""<>]+/thumbs/[^""<>]+)"""
```

Answer (score 4):

Nongreedy regular expressions can be slow because the engine has to do a lot of backtracking.

This one uses only greedy expressions:

```
@"""([^""]*/thumbs/[^""]*)"""
```

Instead of matching the least amount of anything, it matches as many non-double-quotes as it can.

Answer (score 3):

If you're parsing (X)HTML, consider using a proper parser.

See: [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) for some C# examples of how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that .+? also consumes "s, so it continues to match outside of the src attribute. Use this instead:

```
m = Regex.Match(page, @"""([^""]+/thumbs/[^""]+)""");
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you have regular expression you use static field and specify `RegexOptions.Compiled` option:

```
static Regex template = new Regex(@"""(.+?/thumbs/.+?)""", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: A certain number of Regex objects get cached automatically, so storing one in a field won't necessarily have any effect on performance. Also, `Compiled` regexes may be faster, but they're much more expensive to create; whether you should use that option depends on how you're using the regex. http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2004/11/12/256783.aspx